# Get rid of unwanted user listing in GNOME3 (lock screen, login screen and settings)

Tags: users, login, gnome3

At the login screen and also in the system settings I see a user that I don't really want to see in any interactive context. After all I am not being shown the `nobody` user (UID 65534)

Here's how that looks (I have no idea how to make a screenshot from the user list on the login screen, though):

[image: Showing the undesired user]

The details for that user account and the group of the same name can be gleaned from the output of the following sequence of commands (`$` -> as user, `#` -> as `root`):

```
$ getent passwd libvirt-qemu
libvirt-qemu:x:64055:128:Libvirt Qemu,,,:/var/lib/libvirt:/usr/sbin/nologin
$ id libvirt-qemu
uid=64055(libvirt-qemu) gid=128(kvm) groups=128(kvm),64055(libvirt-qemu)
$ getent group libvirt-qemu
libvirt-qemu:x:64055:libvirt-qemu
# getent shadow libvirt-qemu
libvirt-qemu:!:18204:0:99999:7:::
# getent gshadow libvirt-qemu
libvirt-qemu:!::libvirt-qemu
```

Other than two users with UID 1000 and 1001 respectively, these are the only non-system users:

```
# getent passwd |awk -F : '$3 ~ /^[1-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]+/ {print $3 " " $1}'|sort -n
64055 libvirt-qemu
65534 nobody
```

I crafted the regex intentionally to leave out the two four-digit entries for privacy reasons.

**Question:** so how can I get rid of that user being listed in interactive contexts when that user clearly is not meant to be used interactively?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the value for the `SystemAccount` key (in section `[User]`) in `/var/lib/AccountsService/users/libvirt-qemu` (or whatever the equivalent on your distro is) to `true` and restart AccountsService using `sudo systemctl restart accounts-daemon.service`. If there is no such line or file for that user, you can copy it from another user.

The contents of said file should look at least like this:

```
[User]
SystemAccount=true
```

Comment: Bingo! That was it. Sweet. I copied the contents of `gdm`, which seemed to provide what you suggested.